# How to pass auth token to UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, youtube

I want to play private videos of you tube in my app via UIWebView. Requirement is user should not be asked user name and password for playing that video. So I have done Google authentication in my code, and getting auth token. I need to send that auth token to UIWebView so that it can play that private video without asking user about the user name and password (as we have made channel on you tube and we have user name and password). If any body have solution please provide. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube integration in iOS SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724981/youtube-integration-in-ios-sdk)